# Probability of an integer factoring "nicely" into exactly two integers smaller than a certain bound.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $N$ be some margin, and $1\leq k\leq N$ some integer. What is the probability, that $k$ factors nicely, in the sense that $\exists x,y\leq\sqrt{N}\in\mathbb{N}:k=xy$. It is obviously bound by the number of primes between $\sqrt{N}$ and $N$, and all the possible numbers, but thats about all, i can think of, to calculate this probability (or more precisely, the approximate number of occurences of such $k$:
$$\frac{N}{\ln(N)}-\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\ln(\sqrt{N})}\leq |\{\sqrt{N}\leq k\leq N:\exists x,y\leq\sqrt{N}:k=xy\}|\leq N - \sqrt{N}$$
The left side is the approximate number of primes between $\sqrt{N}$ and $N$, and the right side all numbers between $N$ and $\sqrt{N}$. Some help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, if it factors, it isn't prime, so it's $1$ minus the "probability" of being prime.

Comment: @saulspatz not factor into two primes. factor into any two integers x,y. For example $N = 16$. $15$ isnt a prime, but it doesnt factor into two numbers below $4$

Comment: I didn't say anything about the product of two primes.  A number factors "nicely" if and only if it is not a prime.

Comment: That's [not a trivial problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108912/number-of-elements-in-the-set-1-cdots-n-cdot-1-cdots-n).

Comment: @DanielFischer thats exactly what i was looking for. i am guessing this is a duplicate then, or at least gets me closer to what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: One difficulty is deciding on an appropriate probability measure on the integers. And then deciding on probabilities of primes over 'chunks' of positive integers. Maybe google 'probabilistic number theory'.